# Django giving 500 instead of 404 for unknown URLs when debug is false

Tags: python, django, django-templates, http-status-code-404

Django = 2.1.x

Python = 3.7.x

If Debug is True - it returns a 404.

If Debug is False - it gives a 500 error.

My `project.urls` file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", app1.views.log_in, name="log_in"),
    path("log_in/", app1.views.log_in, name="log_in"),
    path("logout/", app1.views.log_out, name="logout"),
    path("launcher/", app1.views.launcher, name="launcher"),
    path("app2/", include("app2.urls")),
    path("app3/", include("app3.urls")),
]
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
Project_directory
    static_directory
        ...js files and css files and such...
    templates_directory
        400.html
        403.html
        404.html
        500.html
        base.html (all apps extend this page, which works great)
    project_directory
        urls.py
        settings.py
        ...other files...
    app1_directory
        views.py
        models.py
        templates_directory
            app1
                ...template files...
        ...other app1 files/directories...
    app2_directory
        ...app2 directories and files...
    app3_directory
        ...app3 directories and files...
```

When I `python manage.py runserver` and I hit a URL I know doesn't exist (like `http://project/randomtrash.php`) it gives an appropriate 404 if `DEBUG = True`

If `DEBUG = False` then hitting that same URL will give a `500` and the `500.html` displays.

Important parts of my `settings.py` look like this:

```
# These two settings are only for testing purposes and are different
# In production
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

ROOT_URLCONF = "project.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        # DIRS lets the apps extend base.html
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "project.context_processors.app_context",
                "project.context_processors.registrations",
            ]
        },
    }
]

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had to do with the `app_context` and `registrations` context_processors.

In those they were using the `request` and resolving things against it (i.e. `resolve(request.path).app_name`) which would never match up on a `404` or other error - thus causing a `500` error in response.

I've wrapped each of those couple functions in it's own simple if statement for now:

```
if request.resolver_match:
    ...do stuff...
```

Now all the errors render appropriately as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Django renders the debug page when DEBUG=True, ignoring the 404 page.

See [Show 404 page on django when DEBUG=True](https://spapas.github.io/2015/04/29/django-show-404-page/)

Comment: Yes, that's how I know it registers a 404.

Comment: When I set it to False, it is giving a `500` error and no longer registering as a 404